# Why does my heroku app only work when rails server is running locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, heroku

Sorry, this is my first time deploying my site on Heroku. The main elements of website does run, but none of my fetch requests are working. So, none of the data from my Rails backend is rendering. I've been receiving this in my console whenever the site is supposed to make a fetch request (to localhost:3000) => "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
Should I not be trying to fetch from localhost when my site is deployed on heroku?

I've tried creating a Procfile, updating my production and development environments, etc.

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}
```

Comment: Does this also have a front end deployed on heroku as well? Ie. 2 heroku instances? If so, then you should be using the external url to communicate across the 2 instances. Otherwise if this is just the rails app, then you should be using url helpers, which should take care of everything for you (you might have to specify the heroku public url somewhere in the rails config, or set something in the heroku env variables).

Comment: @baseballlover723 Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using a React/Redux frontend. The domain for the frontend is https://placardny.herokuapp.com/, while that of the backend is different. Is that what you mean by an external url?

Comment: are they hosted together, or separately? ie. do you need to deploy 2 things or 1 thing. If its 1 thing, then your hosting them together and using local host should work. But if your hosting them separately, they you have to use the backend url, since the backend and frontend aren't on the same machine

Comment: @baseballlover723 sorry about the late response-- Yes, they are hosted separately so I'm fetching from my Heroku backend. It doesn't seem to be reaching it at all though. Is it a production/development issue?

Comment: So you can't reach your heroku backend using the herokuapp url from your front end?

Comment: @baseballlover723 Yeah so when I try to console log the data I should be receiving, I get back nothing. All fields are empty in Redux as well.